# Android camera: general ghosting issues

Tags: android, image-processing, camera, ocr, low-level

I am developing an android camera app. The camera pictures are later processed by OCR, so the picture must be as sharp as possible.

If you shake the camera, it looks as if the digital camera overlays multiple images, to create the effect of motion blur:

Example 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqrmd.jpg

Example 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBx6F.jpg

If you examine the pictures closely, the motion blur looks to consist of 2 or 3 images taken in quick succession and blended together to simulate light exposure. I understand that this amounts to the way digital cameras work.

But I'd prefer having a single crisp image rather than a properly exposed one. The app can use histogram corrections to make the text readable again for OCR. The image does not have to appeal to the human eye.

Is there a way to better control the camera to get these sort of raw image snapshots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some limited success using the "Action" scene mode on the camera. Not much, but it's  as far as you can get.